# Isekai manga where male protagonist gives sweets from his original world as offerings to goddesses

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's an isekai manga, and is likely to be a light novel adaptation. I read this sometime last year before MangaDex's maintenance break.

The goddess who originally transported the male protagonist to the other world demanded he give her offerings in exchange for some kind of power (I can't recall what). I believe he has a power to somehow get sweets from his original world—it may be from an item menu/shop that only he could use, or something similar. He offers them by putting out the sweets, praying, and the sweets disappear. The goddess loves the sweets so much that she demands more of different varieties.

I remember one scene where the protagonist created chocolate (or something else) and the goddess got jealous that she didn't get to eat it, and immediately demanded he offer her some.

Eventually, other goddesses find out that this one goddess was getting sweets, so they get jealous and wanted the sweets as well. So, they ask the boy to also offer them treats. I think there was a scene where he offered a whole basket full of various sweets. The original goddess gets upset that her secret got found out, because she wanted to keep the sweets for herself.

I'm not exactly sure but I think the group of goddesses wanted to keep this a secret because it was considered forbidden by another god/goddess.

Comment: Does he also have a giant wolf companion?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I don't recall the characteristics of his companions. If you're thinking it's [Tondemo Skill de Isekai Hourou Meshi](https://myanimelist.net/manga/105747/Tondemo_Skill_de_Isekai_Hourou_Meshi), this isn't the manga. I'll update the original post with this.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots SORRY, I'm wrong. It did turn out to be the source. I didn't remember that there were multiple goddesses in this. It turns out I was recalling chapter 30, and thought it was a different manga.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*[Tondemo Skill de Isekai Houro Meshi](https://myanimelist.net/manga/105747/Tondemo_Skill_de_Isekai_Hourou_Meshi)* fits with it being an isekai manga where the protagonist gains favor, and thereby power, by his cooking skills (aided by his skill, which lets him pull Japanese foods into this fantasy world), although his first companion is a giant *fenrir*, [Fel](https://tondemo-skill.fandom.com/wiki/Fel).

[image: Front cover of Tondemo Skill de Isekai Houro Meshi]

He does later seduce several goddesses over to his side by virtue of sweets, such as [Ninlil](https://tondemo-skill.fandom.com/wiki/Ninlil), [Kishar](https://tondemo-skill.fandom.com/wiki/Kishar), [Rusalka](https://tondemo-skill.fandom.com/wiki/Rusalka), and [Agni](https://tondemo-skill.fandom.com/wiki/Agni).

Comment: Thanks so much! Yea, turns out I misremembered a few details, such as the goddess transporting the protagonist to the other world.

Comment: :) Congrats! By the by, you can [edit] my answer to add more details (as a new user, you'll have to be approved, but you'll earn points if approved). Everyone can edit anyone's posts here. Going around and fixing typos/formatting is a decent way to gain some quick rep points when you start.