# Boy with glasses who cooks, and has a familiar slime

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

A boy with glasses goes to another world, cooks for a guild, and gets a familiar slime. All of his items are overpowered in different ways. And he doesn’t like doing appraisal stuff, but he does all that stuff just to make better food.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "for a guilt"?

Comment: In retrospect, a "guild" makes perfect sense for the average isekai.

Answer (score 3):

A partial match is [*Tondemo Skill de Isekai Hourou Meshi*](https://tondemo-skill.fandom.com/wiki/Tondemo_Skill_de_Isekai_Hourou_Meshi_Wiki).

[image: Front cover of Tondemo Skill de Isekai Hourou Meshi]

> Mukouda Tsuyoshi, summoned from modern Japan to a different world of sword and magic. He thought of what kind of a huge adventure was waiting for him, but actually, Mukoda is just a civilian who got caught in a Hero Summoning. And that Mukoda’s base status shabby compared to the legitimate heroes. On top of that, the king who summoned Mukouda and the rest were suspicious, and Mukouda left the castle by himself realizing. The only thing that Mukoda could rely on in this world is his unique skill Net Supermarket - it can only order goods from modern Japan to the different world.

Mukoda does not wear glasses, but his access to a Food Store and Item Box with Evaluate capability, as well as his knowledge of foreign recipes, makes him able to cook amazing food for his party (not a guild as far as I've read) that boosts stats. In addition to the Food Store and Item Box (which can only have Evaluate if you're from another world), he has a Magic Stove that lets him cook rapidly anywhere. The familiar most people remember him getting is [Fel](https://tondemo-skill.fandom.com/wiki/Fel), the giant Fenrir (wolf), but his next familiar is [Sui](https://tondemo-skill.fandom.com/wiki/Sui) the slime.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/254142/23243, which mentions his third familiar, a goddess.

Comment: IIRC his third familiar was a pixie (tiny) dragon. The Goddesses give him boons in return for his cooking and net market items.