# Manga about a feminine boy with "God's eyes" who cooks for a guild

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

About a boy who wears glasses goes into a video game. He cooks for a Guild and he has appraisal (God's eyes). He is feminine without it feeling overbearing to the story.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the boy's hair?

Comment: Mostly black and white and black

Comment: Does he have a familiar slime, as per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261730/boy-with-glasses-who-cooks-and-has-a-familiar-slime?noredirect=1&lq=1?

Comment: {facepalm} I just realized why the question sounded so similar... sorry for giving you the same answer twice, but at least now you've confirmed it's not the right one.

Comment: Please modify your old question with any updated details rather than asking again.

Comment: I founded it !!! It is saikyou no kanteishi tth dare no koto? It is really good and it’s like a fantasy slice of life comedy type manga so many hours of searching  to find it Read it

Comment: @AshleyWalker Glad to hear you found it. Could you add it as a self-accepted answer on your earlier question? Include the title, a brief description, and how it matches (or differs) from the points in your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be [*Tondemo Skill de Isekai Hourou Meshi*](https://tondemo-skill.fandom.com/wiki/Tondemo_Skill_de_Isekai_Hourou_Meshi_Wiki) as per [Isekai manga where male protagonist gives sweets from his original world as offerings to goddesses](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254142/).

[image: Front cover of Tondemo Skill de Isekai Hourou Meshi]

> Mukouda Tsuyoshi, summoned from modern Japan to a different world of sword and magic. He thought of what kind of a huge adventure was waiting for him, but actually, Mukoda is just a civilian who got caught in a Hero Summoning. And that Mukoda’s base status shabby compared to the legitimate heroes. On top of that, the king who summoned Mukouda and the rest were suspicious, and Mukouda left the castle by himself realizing. The only thing that Mukoda could rely on in this world is his unique skill Net Supermarket - it can only order goods from modern Japan to the different world.

Mukoda doesn't wear glasses, but his access to a Food Store and Item Box with Evaluate capability, as well as his knowledge of foreign recipes, makes him able to cook amazing food for his party (not a guild as far as I've read) that boosts stats. In addition to the Food Store and Item Box (which can only have Evaluate if you're from another world), he has a Magic Stove that lets him cook rapidly anywhere.

Comment: Much of this copied from my answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261730/boy-with-glasses-who-cooks-and-has-a-familiar-slime

Comment: Not it but nice try